# Avoid specifying the same arguments multiple times in different Eclipse launchers?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP product and two launchers to launch it in two different modes. Some arguments are present in all three, some are specific to one or the other.

I have had the problem in the past that one of these gets modified without the others, and I don't immediately notice, so the deployed product ends up running differently to the debug launched versions.

It doesn't help that `.product`s are xml like files, while `.launcher`s store VM arguments in a string on a single line, so it is difficult to compare them.

For instance my Product is created a `.product` file containing things like:

```
   <launcherArgs>
      <vmArgs>-Declipse.pluginCustomization=../config/pluginCustomization.ini
-Dmode=live</vmArgs>
   </launcherArgs>
```

And this is intended to have the same vm arguments as my live debug launcher:

```
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS" value="-Declipse.pluginCustomization=../config/pluginCustomization.ini&#10;-Dmode=live"/>
```

But the dummy debug launcher should have some arguments which are the same, and others which are different:

```
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS" value="-Declipse.pluginCustomization=../config/pluginCustomization.ini&#10;-Dmode=dummy"/>
```

So, can I avoid specifying the same arguments multiple times in different Eclipse launchers?

Ideally I would like to either default my launcher to the arguments in the product and override any argument which is different, or include just the common items in the product and have the differences in the launchers, but everything I have tried so far has failed.

Comment: You can define your own variables (like ${project}) using the Variables... buttons on the Run Configurations dialog (and in Preferences > Run/Debug > String Substitution)

Comment: Sorry @greg-449 I shouldn't have used variable substitutions in my examples, they were intended as a placeholder for the actual paths, but I didn't make that clear. The `.product` vmargs aren't expanded when making a product, so I can't use variables there.